# Controlling the number of attempts in a single spark job without using spark.yarn.maxAttempts parameter

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where I am running a spark job that will read from a hive table and then write to another Hive table.
What i want to achieve is that when i launch my Spark job for this, the job should fail in its first attempt but then be successful in its second attempt. 
The spark parameter: spark.yarn.maxAttempts is set to its default value,i.e., 2 and I do not have control over it in my environment.

Below is the code i have tried (thanks to @Jacek):

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext  
class TaskContextTest {
    val atmptNumber = TaskContext.get.attemptNumber
    if (atmptNumber==0) {
      println("Failing the task in first attempt")
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("attemptNumber == 0")
    }
    println(s"Proceeding to the 2nd attempt")
}
```

The error i am getting is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
```

Comment: `TaskContext.get` gives you `None` and hence the exception. It is going to be available on an executor only so the question is how do you use this `TaskContextTest` class? Share more code.

Comment: I tried the code shared above in spark-shell and it is working fine now. BUt the same error crops up when i am calling this class in my framework. Looks like i have to look into the properties of my framework and figure out how to integrate this with it. Due to copyright and proprietary constraints, i wont be able to share code related to the framework. Thanks @Jacek for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a work around to fail in the first attempt and success in the second attempt with out using TaskContext.

1. Create a temp folder in the hive datalake/hdfs path.
2. If the folder is empty, write a dummy file to that and fail the process. (1st attempt)
3. In the second attempt as this folder is not empty, you can got to else and execute your code in the second attempt.
4. Clean that folder in the second attempt so that when your the job again, it will fail for the first attempt.

Sudo Code :

```
if(Temp Folder is Empty ){  
//Executes for First attempt
Write Dummy File to Temp Folder
Raise an Exceptio to Fail
}
else{
//Executes for second attempt
....Execute your code 
Clean Temp Folder
}
```

Hope it helps you.